# Android Studio: Is it possible to use a string array in a setText?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make Hangman game where the guessed letter should appear on the screen. I've made a textview where I want them to be. I'm trying to make it like this:

```
 ArrayList<String> bogstaver = gal.getBrugteBogstaver();
 tv2.setText(bogstaver);
```

But I get an error:

> ```
> Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.string>)'
> ```

Here's the full stack trace from logcat:

```
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.hadi.galgeleg, PID: 21678
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.hadi.galgeleg.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:48)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Use `tv2.setText(bogstaver.toString());`

Comment: how exactly do you want to display the string array? like this "[text1, text2, text3]" ?

Comment: @XiaoyuYu: Yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have told you in comments, to pass the value of the `ArrayList` as a string, use `tv2.setText(bogstaver.toString())`.

However, as your stack trace tells you:

> 11-02 19:01:12.000 21678-21678/com.example.hadi.galgeleg E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference

`tv2` appears to be `null`.